# What exception should be thrown when the query returned fewer records than I requested?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, exception

What exception should be thrown when the query returned fewer records than I requested?

```java
void hasDbSameQuantityOfUuids(List<UUID> uuids) {     // uuids: 1, 2, 3
    List<UUID> retrievedUuids = getUuids();           // retrievedUuids = 2, 3
    if(retrievedUuids.size() == uuids.size()) {
         // throw new ...
    }
    
    ...
}

List<UUID> getUuids(List<UUID> uuids) {
    return new JPAQuery<>(entityManager)
                    .select(...)
                    .from(...)
                    .where(object.uuid.in(uuids))
                    .fetch();
}
```

- DB: 2, 3
- Output: 2, 3

When it comes to API - Which Http status is best for this case?

Comment: It depends on whether that's an actual problem or just a "overfiltered" request. But I'd say "404 not found" would be appropriate. IMHO, its just a 200 and return what has been found.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I have to check it since I can't perform certain actions on non existing resources in next steps. Thanks, `404 NOT_FOUND` looks ok.